# how to resend multipart request

Tags: flutter, httpinterceptor

I am retrying my api call if get 401 response but when Retrying I am ending with an following exception
[image: Bad state] following is my code for retrying multipart I had used http_interceptor package for retrying Api Calls
interceptor.dart

```
class AuthorizationInterceptor extends InterceptorContract {
  @override
  Future<BaseRequest> interceptRequest({required BaseRequest request}) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final extractData =
        json.decode(prefs.getString('userData')!) as Map<String, dynamic>;

    final Map<String, String> headers = Map.from(request.headers);
    headers['Authorization'] = await extractData['accessToken'];
    print(
        'this is from AuthorizationInterceptor: ${extractData['accessToken']}');
    // TODO: implement interceptRequest

    return request.copyWith(
      headers: headers,
    );
  }
```

retry.dart

```
class ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy extends RetryPolicy {
  BuildContext context;
  ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy(this.context);
  @override
  // TODO: implement maxRetryAttempts
  int get maxRetryAttempts => 2;

  @override
  Future<bool> shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse(BaseResponse response) async {
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      print('retry token started');
      //perform token refresh,get the new token and update it in the secure storage

      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).restoreAccessToken();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I am using interceptors in my widget following is my code where I am using interceptors and using retry policy

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var flutterFunctions = Provider.of<FlutterFunctions>(context);

    // print('this is from insert package${token.token}');
    ApiCalls repository = ApiCalls(
      client: InterceptedClient.build(
        retryPolicy: ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy(context),
        interceptors: [
          AuthorizationInterceptor(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

following is my restore access token method

```
Future<void> restoreAccessToken() async {
    print('restoreAccessToken started');

    //print(token);
    final url = '${Ninecabsapi().urlHost}${Ninecabsapi().login}/$sessionId';

    var response = await http.patch(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': accessToken!
      },
      body: json.encode(
        {"refresh_token": refreshtoken},
      ),
    );
    var userDetails = json.decode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      print(userDetails['messages']);
    }

    sessionId = userDetails['data']['session_id'];
    accessToken = userDetails['data']['access_token'];
    accessTokenExpiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
      Duration(seconds: userDetails['data']['access_token_expiry']),
    );
    refreshToken = userDetails['data']['refresh_token'];
    refreshTokenExpiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
      Duration(seconds: userDetails['data']['refresh_token_expiry']),
    );
    final userData = json.encode({
      'sessionId': sessionId,
      'refreshToken': refreshToken,
      'refreshExpiry': refreshTokenExpiryDate!.toIso8601String(),
      'accessToken': accessToken,
      'accessTokenExpiry': accessTokenExpiryDate!.toIso8601String()
    });
    //print(userDetails);

    notifyListeners();
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs.setString('userData', userData);
    print("this is from restoreAcessToken :$userDetails");
    final extractData =
        json.decode(prefs.getString('userData')!) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print('restore access token: ${extractData['accessToken']}');
    reset();
  }
```

Comment: Plz mark where in your code the error happens!

Comment: Also, I can't see where you're using your `shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse()` method...

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård I am using http_interceptor package where you will had clear idea what I am doing

Comment: You still haven't marked where in the code the error occurs! And plz provide the code where you call `shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse()`. 

Comment: error is coming from ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy where I should resend multipart request again but I don't know how to resend the request

Comment: That's kind of vague!... I was hoping for the exact letter where it happens.

Comment: you can see in the image above the error is coming from multipart_file.dart if I resend the request inside shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse() method then error is gone

Comment: this is not an error to say on which line it Is exactly happening it is an exception

Comment: And why won't you show us where you call your `shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse()` method...? It's easier to help you if you answer qns.

Comment: as I said  before if you go through http_interceptor package you will understand what I am doing

Comment: Instead of making us go through that whole package and guess which parts you have used and which parts you have changed or left out, you should just show us your code. Probably, the error is in something that you've changed or left out! Likely without knowing. So thanks for updating!

Comment: ok if any other requirement please inform me

Comment: So are you still looking for help on this, or did you solve it?

Comment: If you are, could we plz see your `.restoreAccessToken()` method, as well?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård I had updated the question please check

Comment: Hi. Any progress on the above? I've been a bit busy and couldn't get back to this sooner... (I've noticed, however, that your code bits above are incomplete. They lack brackets and braces. It's always good to put as complete code as possible (although removing unnecessary details!) so that helpers can just copy-paste it into their IDE and run it.)

Comment: hmm thank you for responding above mention code is not working therefore I had imported import 'package:http/retry.dart'; from http its works fine to retry api  calls

Comment: Oh, ok. So you no longer need help?

Comment: You know, you should post that as an answer to your own qn! It could help some future developer with the same problem. 

Comment: hmm at present regarding this question problem was solved but I need help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73835435/zsh-command-not-found-flutterfire

Comment: regarding this question following answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73724685/proxy-provider-is-not-updating-value

Comment: actually I had tried 2 methods to retry api call upon error this is one of my method but it failed but as mentioned in previous comment that method works perfect to retry api call

Answer (score -1):

As a rule. You must NOT write using the same Stream/MultipartFile more than once. If you need to retry sending to the same destination, you have to use a new MultipartFile each time you retry.

Comment: regarding this question following answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73724685/proxy-provider-is-not-updating-value