# zsh: command not found: flutterfire

Tags: flutter, firebase, macos

I am using Mac OS. i am trying register my project in firebase and use Crashlytics in firebase to check if any crash occurs in my app I had used

```
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```

command to install flutter tools it worked fine after that I tried to run

```
flutterfire configure
```

command but it throws

> zsh: command not found: flutterfire

I know that I must set $path variable but to set path variable I don't know where is my flutter tools has installed in my Mac. kindly help me to set $PATH variable

Answer (score 9):

we can use these steps

1. `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`
2. Then add `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"` to .bashrc by `code ~/.bashrc`
3. Then `source ~/.bashrc`
4. `flutterfire configure`

Comment: worked for me, Mac M3

Answer (score 2):

Once you run the following command

```
    dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

you should get the following output

[image: output]

The output is telling you the executable is not on your path variable

```
    export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

Either run the export command in your terminal
OR
Add the command to your .zhrc file

Answer (score 1):

run before `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`

Comment: I had tried but not working same result

Comment: Really? What answer do you get after the above command, then?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård zsh: command not found: flutterfire

Comment: No.... I said what happens when you run THIS command: `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`?

Comment: if I run the command flutterfire_cli flutter fire is activated after activation I am running flutterfire configure command to configure firebase in my project at that time I am facing error

Comment: you need to export the path to flutterfire_cli because it is not globaly install
run `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"`

Comment: I had enter that command but it is asking `dquote>` what should I do now