# Flutterfire Command not found even after setting path and not being installed into the .pub-cache/bin folder

Tags: flutter, firebase

Basically the title:

Trying to get Firebase running on my Flutter Project.
I installed firebase-tools GLOBALLY using npm and managed to login.

Following the official docs from google I am able to execute

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

which returns

```
+ ansi_styles 0.3.2+1s... (1.0s)
+ args 2.3.1
+ async 2.9.0
+ characters 1.2.1
+ ci 0.1.0
+ cli_util 0.3.5
+ clock 1.1.1
+ collection 1.17.0
+ dart_console 1.1.2
+ deep_pick 0.10.0
+ ffi 2.0.1
+ file 6.1.4
+ flutterfire_cli 0.2.6
+ http 0.13.5
+ http_parser 4.0.2
+ interact 2.1.1
+ intl 0.17.0
+ json_annotation 4.7.0
+ matcher 0.12.12
+ meta 1.8.0
+ path 1.8.2
+ petitparser 5.1.0
+ platform 3.1.0
+ process 4.2.4
+ pub_semver 2.1.2
+ pub_updater 0.2.2
+ pubspec 2.3.0
+ quiver 3.1.0
+ source_span 1.9.1
+ stack_trace 1.11.0
+ string_scanner 1.1.1
+ term_glyph 1.2.1
+ tint 2.0.0
+ typed_data 1.3.1
+ uri 1.0.0
+ win32 2.7.0 (3.0.1 available)
+ xml 6.2.0
+ yaml 3.1.1
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/MYUSER/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/characters-1.2.1".
```

I already added the path to my .zshrc

```
export PATH=/Users/MYUSER/Desktop/codeBin/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/MYUSER/Desktop/codeBin/flutter/bin:$PATH
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

Running `flutterfire configure` returns

```
zsh: command not found: flutterfire
```

Already tried stuff like:
[zsh: command not found: flutterfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73835435/zsh-command-not-found-flutterfire)

Already spent 2 hours trying to fix this problem. Any tips on how to fix or further debug this would be appreciated (Even though I bet it is something incredible stupid :P)

Running MacOS if it matters.

**Edit**

I found out that following the steps mentioned above does not put `flutterfire` into my `/.pub-cache/bin`

I still have not figured out how to install flutterfire correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It appears you ran the command wrong as it's saying "not found: flutter fire" instead of "not found: flutterfire". It's a single word.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in my question. I ran the command correctly ^^ Edited the typo out

Comment: Can you type `echo $PATH` and post the output in your question? I imagine that your path should be something closer to this on the last line:  export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin". Can you try executing the flutterfire binary from $HOME/.pub-cache/bin to see if it fails there as well? It sounds like an issue with $PATH

Comment: ```echo $PATH``` returned the following ```/Users/yannick/Desktop/codeBin/flutter/bin:/Users/yannick/Desktop/codeBin/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin```

I cd'd into the directory of my pub-cache but there wasn't at bin folder to begin with! Huh! Guess I found out why it wasn't finding that command then... Now I gotta figure out why flutterfire isn't where its supposed to be... Thanks for giving my tired brain the right nudge!